# How can you tell an UIViewController that a button is pressed in an UIPopOverController?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

i think the title is self explaining. 
I have an UIPopOverController, in it is a tableview and when i select a cell, i want to tell it the UIViewController.

Is there an easy solution or do i need KeyValueObserving or notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post an NSNotification from the tableview and add the UIViewController as an observer.

Comment: Think that's the easiest method.

Answer (score 1):

you could move with one of two approaches as per your choice.

**first :** using delegate/protocol.
http://www.thepensiveprogrammer.com/2010/05/objective-c-protocols-and-delegates.html

**second:** Set your UIViewController as the target for your UIButton.

for example

```
[btn addTarget:myController action:@selector(ActionWillBePerformedInController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting an NSNotification will work well... you can also create a callback object and selector in your UITableViewController class.

you could initialize your UITableViewController with a callback object and callback selector

```
initWithTarget:(id)theTarget andSelector:(SEL) theSelector
```

...save off the values to properties

then from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in your tableView... call

```
[self.target performSelector:self.selector];
```

using this methodology, you can define your own callback methods as you wish.. from your ViewController class that created the popover, you could do something like this...

```
[[MyTableView alloc] initWithTarget:(self) andSelector:@selector(popoverControllerDidRequestClose)];
```